# After my computer boots it shows a black screen, how can i fix this?

Tags: boot

I was messing around with some display options, i managed to flip the screen, that is when it went black. All i can see on it is my upside down cursor and upon restart the ubuntu loading screen pops up but it returns to the black screen.

It is a dual boot on a macbook.

I apologize if i am unfamiliar with with linux as I have had it installed for less than a week.

when it is rebooted connected to a tv via an HDMI cable it performs like before but as soon as i disconnect the screen goes black and the cursor  becomes upside down. when the cable is plugged in after the boot it remains black while the tv screen has my back ground.

Comment: Can you recall which display options you've altered ?

Comment: I used the 180 degree flip in the display settings.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use a tv monitor to change the display options back to normal.